# How to make a playing area with fixed square dimensions?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to have a playing area with a square dimension, and a sidebar GUI that can be resized according to the resolution. I drew a picture that [might help explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRJY5.jpg)

I tried following a tutorial [here](http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.sg/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html) but the actual dimensions in the build I run seem to be different from what I configure it to in my editor. Also, how do I get the coordinates of the middle of the square (to instantiate something)? Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial you linked it says:

> When running your game from within Unity's editor, be sure to have the Game >window open and visible in the editor when you run the game. There's >currently a bug in Unity 3.0 (and possibly in earlier versions as well) where >the window resolution reported to the script does not match the actual >resolution of the window inside the editor if the window isn't visible at the >time the play button is pressed, leading to a viewport with the wrong size.

Did you took notice to this?

Also what do you mean by taking the coordinates in the center of the square? If you mean the actual screen, then you should get a point based on the square dimensions like:

```
Vector2 point;
Rect rect = camera.rect;
point.x = rect.x/2;
point.y = rect.y/2;
```

But if you want the point in 3D space where the camera is pointing, you can use the default method ViewportToWorldPoint, as shown here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/189731/how-would-i-find-a-point-in-front-of-my-cam.html
It should look like this:

```
float distanceFromViewPort = 1 //change 1 to the distance you wish the instance to appear away from the camera.
Vector3 point = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector(0.5,0.5,distanceFromCamera));
```